# How to Flush NginX's SSL buffer mid-request for Server Push

Tags: nginx, ssl

I'm writing an app that uses long polling to push messages to clients.  It doesn't end the request when it finishes sending a message though: it just flushes.  It works fine, even when I proxy it through nginx and access it over the internet.

```
upstream app {
  server localhost:1000;
}

server {
    listen 80;    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        client_max_body_size 20m;
        proxy_redirect off;
        send_timeout 86400;
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;
        proxy_buffering off;
        gzip off;
    }
}
```

That is, until I enable SSL on nginx.  Then it won't flush anymore.  I can work around this by setting `ssl_buffer_size` to 1, but this negatively impacts performance.

```
server {
    listen 443;
    ssl_certificate cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key key.pem;
    ssl_buffer_size 1;
    ...
}
```

With any other buffer size, NginX will not flush the last incomplete buffer unless the request ends.  Is there any way to force it to?  Am I foolish for wanting this?

I have noticed that flush works as long as the amount of data is below 61450 bytes.  If you try to flush much more than that, it starts buffering.

Comment: Check out tcp_nopush option.

Comment: I'm pretty sure tcp_nopush is the opposite of what I want.

Comment: I've found that I can flush as much data as I want if I upgrade to websockets.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's exactly what you want ... As every **option** it can be turned **on** or **off**. Turning it **off** will avoid using `TCP_CORK` on TCP sockets, so it will prevent amassing data to a minimum length before sending it. `TCP_NODELAY` (tcp_nodelay **option**) is also something to look into as turning it **off** will avoid waiting for client's ACK before sending further data. This is TCP behaviour, using websockets won't change that as it's layered over TCP.

Comment: Off is the default for that setting.